# Conan don't create arrow bundle dependency

Tags: conan, apache-arrow, apache-arrow-cpp

In our project, we use *arrow10.0.0* and each time for our builds, we made an arrow build. Now we want to use `conan` to make our builds faster. Using the `arrow.cmake` file, we could determine which components should be *Bundled*, and then made a link to  `libarrow_bundled_dependencies.a` , but with the help of `conan`, we can’t do this and the `libarrow_bundled_dependencies.a` file is not created. Can you help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

conan install . --build=missing

`find -name ~/.conan/*bundle*`

Nothing find

```
import os

from conan import ConanFile
from conan.errors import ConanInvalidConfiguration
from conan.tools.build import check_min_cppstd, cross_building
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, CMakeDeps, CMakeToolchain, cmake_layout
from conan.tools.files import apply_conandata_patches, copy, export_conandata_patches, get, rmdir
from conan.tools.microsoft import is_msvc, is_msvc_static_runtime
from conan.tools.scm import Version


class ConanUTest(ConanFile):

    exports = 'VERSION', 'LICENSE', 'README.md'
    exports_sources = 'CMakeLists.txt', 'src/*', 'include/*', 'cmake/*', 'VERSION'
    name = 'mypackage'
    version = '0.1.1'
    # Take just the first line
    license = open('LICENSE').read().split('\n', 1)[0]
    description = open('README.md').read()
    settings = {
        'os': ['Linux'],
        'compiler': [
            'gcc', 'clang', 'intel',
        ],
        'build_type': ['Release'],
        'arch': ['x86', 'x86_64', 'armv8', 'armv8_32', 'armv8.3'],
    }
    generators = 'CMakeDeps', 'deploy'
    options = {'with_arrow': [True, False]}
    default_options = {
        'with_arrow': False,
    }

    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def generate(self):
        tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
        if cross_building(self):
            cmake_system_processor = {
                "armv8": "aarch64",
                "armv8.3": "aarch64",
            }.get(str(self.settings.arch), str(self.settings.arch))
            if cmake_system_processor == "aarch64":
                tc.variables["ARROW_CPU_FLAG"] = "armv8"

        tc.variables["ARROW_DEPENDENCY_SOURCE"] = "AUTO"
        tc.variables['ARROW_BUILD_STATIC'] = True
        tc.variables['ARROW_BUILD_SHARED'] = False
        tc.variables['ARROW_SIMD_LEVEL'] = "AVX2"
        tc.variables["ARROW_DEPENDENCY_USE_SHARED"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_OPENSSL_USE_SHARED"] = True

        tc.variables["ARROW_BUILD_TESTS"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_ENABLE_TIMING_TESTS"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_BUILD_EXAMPLES"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_BUILD_BENCHMARKS"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_BUILD_INTEGRATION"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_EXTRA_ERROR_CONTEXT"] = False

        tc.variables['ARROW_DATASET'] = True
        tc.variables['ARROW_PARQUET'] = True
        tc.variables['ARROW_WITH_RE2'] = True
        tc.variables['ARROW_COMPUTE'] = True
        tc.variables['ARROW_FLIGHT'] = True
        tc.variables['ARROW_WITH_UTF8PROC'] = True

        tc.variables["PARQUET_REQUIRE_ENCRYPTION"] = bool(
            self.options['arrow:encryption'])  # False
        tc.variables["ARROW_CUDA"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_JEMALLOC"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_IPC"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_JSON"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_CSV"] = True
        tc.variables["ARROW_FLIGHT_SQL"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_WITH_UCX"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_WITH_SNAPPY"] = True
        tc.variables["ARROW_BUILD_UTILITIES"] = bool(
            self.options['arrow:cli'])  # False
        tc.variables["ARROW_GANDIVA"] = False
        tc.variables["ARROW_S3"] = False

        tc.variables["ABS_VENDORED"] = True

        tc.variables["ARROW_DEPENDENCY_SOURCE"] = "BUNDLED"
        tc.variables["c-ares_SOURCE"] = "BUNDLED"
        tc.variables["re2_SOURCE"] = "BUNDLED"
        tc.variables["absl_SOURCE"] = "BUNDLED"
        tc.variables["Protobuf_SOURCE"] = "BUNDLED"
        tc.variables["Snappy_SOURCE"] = "BUNDLED"
        tc.variables["gRPC_SOURCE"] = "BUNDLED"
        tc.variables["ZLIB_SOURCE"] = "BUNDLED"
        tc.variables["Thrift_SOURCE"] = "BUNDLED"
        tc.variables["utf8proc_SOURCE"] = "BUNDLED"

        tc.variables["ARROW_INCLUDE_DIR"] = True
        tc.variables["ARROW_WITH_THRIFT"] = self._with_thrift()
        tc.variables["ARROW_UTF8PROC_USE_SHARED"] = False
        tc.variables["Thrift_SOURCE"] = "BUNDLED"
        if self._with_thrift():
            # a recent thrift does not require boost
            tc.variables["THRIFT_VERSION"] = bool(
                self.dependencies["thrift"].ref.version)
            tc.variables["ARROW_THRIFT_USE_SHARED"] = bool(
                self.dependencies["thrift"].options.shared)

        tc.cache_variables["ENABLE_STATIC"] = "ON"
        tc.cache_variables["ENABLE_BSON"] = "ON"
        tc.cache_variables["ENABLE_TESTS"] = "OFF"
        tc.cache_variables["ENABLE_EXAMPLES"] = "OFF"
        tc.cache_variables["ENABLE_TRACING"] = "OFF"
        tc.cache_variables["ENABLE_COVERAGE"] = "OFF"
        tc.cache_variables["ENABLE_SHM_COUNTERS"] = "OFF"
        tc.cache_variables["ENABLE_MONGOC"] = "OFF"
        tc.cache_variables["ENABLE_MAN_PAGES"] = "OFF"
        tc.cache_variables["ENABLE_HTML_DOCS"] = "OFF"
        tc.generate()

    def configure(self):
        self.options["openssl"].shared = False

        self.options["pcre2"].fPIC = True
        self.options["pcre2"].support_jit = True
        self.options["pcre2"].build_pcre2grep = True

        self.options["arrow"].shared = True
        self.options["arrow"].with_orc = False
        self.options["arrow"].parquet = True
        self.options["arrow"].dataset_modules = True
        self.options["arrow"].with_re2 = True
        self.options["arrow"].compute = True
        self.options["arrow"].with_flight_rpc = True
        self.options["arrow"].with_utf8proc = True
        self.options["arrow"].with_openssl = True
        self.options["arrow"].encryption = False
        self.options["arrow"].with_cuda = False
        self.options["arrow"].with_jemalloc = False
        self.options["arrow"].with_json = False
        self.options["arrow"].with_csv = True
        self.options["arrow"].simd_level = 'avx2'
        self.options["arrow"].with_flight_sql = False
        self.options["arrow"].with_snappy = True
        self.options["arrow"].cli = True
        self.options["arrow"].gandiva = False
        self.options["arrow"].with_s3 = False

        self.options["mongo-c-driver"].with_ssl = False
        self.options["mongo-c-driver"].with_sasl = False
        self.options["mongo-c-driver"].srv = False
        self.options["mongo-c-driver"].with_snappy = False
        self.options["mongo-c-driver"].with_zlib = False
        self.options["mongo-c-driver"].with_zstd = False

        # self.options["gtest"].shared = False

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires('arrow/10.0.0')
        self.requires('openssl/1.1.1t')
        self.requires('pcre2/10.42')
        self.requires('fmt/9.1.0')
        self.requires('mongo-c-driver/1.23.2')
        self.requires('nlohmann_json/3.11.2')
        self.requires('yyjson/0.6.0')
        self.requires('simdjson/3.1.7')
        self.requires('jemalloc/5.3.0')
        self.requires('clipp/1.2.3')
        # self.requires('gtest/1.13.0')
        self.requires('benchmark/1.7.1')
        self.requires('argparse/2.9')
        self.requires('re2/20220601')
        self.requires('xsimd/9.0.1')
        # https://conan.io/center/openssl

    # def build(self):
    #     cmake = CMake(self)
    #     cmake.configure()
    #     cmake.build()

    def system_requirements(self):
        pass

    def package_info(self):

        self.cpp_info.components["libarrow_flight.a"].set_property(
            "pkg_config_name", "flight_rpc")
        self.cpp_info.components["libarrow_flight.a"].libs = [
            f"arrow_flight.a"]

    def package(self):
        if self.options['arrow'].shared:
            self.copy(pattern="*.dll", dst="bin", keep_path=False)
            self.copy(pattern="*.dylib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy(pattern="*.a", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy(pattern="*.h", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy(pattern="*.hpp", dst="lib", keep_path=False)

    def _with_thrift(self, required=False):
        # No self.options.with_thift exists
        return bool(required or self._parquet())

    def _parquet(self, required=False):
        if required or self.options['arrow'].parquet == "auto":
            return bool(self.options.get_safe("substrait", False))
        else:
            return bool(self.options['arrow'].parquet)
```

Comment: It seems you are using some very legacy stuff, like the definition of ``settings`` as a dict (just do ``settings = "os", "compiler", "arch", "build_type"``, forget about the constraints there). Also the use of the ``deploy`` generator there.

Comment: I'd suggest to put the above in a git repo, so it can be reproduced, and file a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues. Also, first try to reduce as much as possible the scope. If it is only the arrow dependency that breaks, remove all the other deps. Make sure to define the Conan version that you are using, the OS, etc.

Comment: Have a look at my example repo that uses conan to bring Arrow into a C++ project and see what's different.